# Javascript, 'for in' loop reading object as string?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have an object that I tried using the for-in loop to iterate over, but it looks like it's looping over each character instead of key:value

```
console.log(myObj);
```

chrome output: `{"gender":"female"}`

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(myObj));
```

chrome output: `"{\"gender\":\"female\"}"`

```
for(var value in myObj){
    console.log(myObj[value]);
}
```

chrome outputs:
`{`
`"`
`f`
....etc...

same behavior regardless of how many key:value pairs there are.
The object in question is `xhr.response` as a result of an ajax call to my server.

Comment: It looks like your object *is* a string. What does `typeof myObj` say?

Comment: http://jsbin.com/yelojiragi/edit?js,console works fine for me, you sure your object isn't just a string?

Comment: What happens if you run `typeof myObj` in Chrome's console?

Comment: @Dai @Jon `string`... well I don't know how my brain missed that connection. Good lord, haha, thanks all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "object" isn't an object, but a string. You need to parse it first in order to use it

```
myObj = JSON.parse(myObj);
for(var value in myObj){
    console.log(myObj[value]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your object must be a string, see the example below. You will have to parse it back to JSON first:

```js
var obj = { "gender": "male", "name": "john" };
document.write('<b>JSON object:</b>' +'<br>')
for(var value in obj){
    document.write(value, ', ', obj[value]+'<br>');
}

document.write('<br><b>String:</b>' +'<br>')
var obj = '{ "gender": "male", "name": "john" }';
for(var value in obj){
    document.write(obj[value]);
}

document.write('<br><br><b>JSON parsed String:</b>' +'<br>')
var obj1 = JSON.parse(obj)
for(var value in obj1){
    document.write(value, ', ', obj1[value]+'<br>');
  }
```